# How to find the altitudes of all triangles?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, pi, polygons

> For Cosine:

For a  triangle with  angles$\angle ABC$ there exist  lengths  $a,b,c$ opposite to the angles.
By using the trigonometric function for cosines, I multiplied the length of $AC\times\cos\angle A$ for example:

> 5+5+4=14 where $\cos\angle B=0.4,\cos\angle A=0.4,\cos\angle C=0.68$  and there are $3$ $\theta$,
>
> $AC\times\cos\angle A=2$ or $BC\times\cos\angle B=2$ which is the place of the altitude and $2+2=4$,
>
> $AB\times\cos\angle B=1.6$
> $BC\times\cos\angle C=3.4$
> $1.6+3.4=5$
> Next step is all I have to use is the Pythagorean theorem.
> Can anyone explain if this is true or false?

for Sine:

> $AC\times\sin\angle B=$
>
> $BC\times\sin\angle A=$

And to find Sine  I subtract 1 from all three $\cos ^2 A,\cos^2 B,\cos^2 C$

And in general the sum of all angles is:

> $\sin^2 A+\sin^2 B+\sin^2 C+\cos^2 A+\cos^2 B+\cos^2 C=3$

Comment: `I multiply the length of the sides times the angle opposite ...` Sorry, this makes no sense at all. Try to rewrite it in a way such that others have at least a chance of guessing what the question asks.

Comment: @dxiv That’s not the nicest way to welcome a new user to our community. I agree that it is confusing, but we are here to build each other up, not tear each other down—especially when the user is probably composing in a foreign language. I hope we can all pay a little kindness forward…

Comment: @user450072 Could you include a visual? It is pretty easy to get lost in all the words and numbers if one doesn’t know exactly what they refer to.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I just re-read what I wrote, and don't see it a `tear each other down` in the least. It was only meant as a honest assessment that the question is unintelligible as posted.

Comment: @dxiv I am glad your intentions were good. Words are powerful tools, especially when we use extremes like “no sense at all” since they're not always fair. Also, *unintelligible* is an uncalled for term. That may be what you perceive, but that is a very hurtful judgement for a student to hear, because it borderline implies that the student is not intelligent and/or is completely failing at trying to ask a question. That's not the attitude we want to diffuse on this site.

Comment: @dxiv In short, this is clearly a student, and you are clearly not. As Maya Angelou said, we must “always be intolerant of ignorance but understanding of illiteracy.” Use your power on this site to dispel ignorance in those who are seeking knowledge, not to leave a bullying comment that makes you look smarter.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor "$\,3$ $\theta$ $5\times0.4=2$or$5\times\angle B\,$" If you find "*unintelligible*" to be too strong of a word for that, please kindly suggest a better one. Seriously now, and will all due consideration to everyone who posts, yet this site has a helpful [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page, while this question violates virtually everything there.

Comment: @dxiv I would say this: “Welcome to our Math.SE community! Here we have a unique system of voting moderators that enforces quality, so please see the page How do I ask a good question? so that your post does not get down-voted or flagged. Also, could you try adding more detail—such as a graphic—and rephrasing the question? I am finding it difficult to understand exactly what you need help with. Good luck, and also check out Math Meta for more questions about how to use Math.SE!”

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor `not to leave a bullying comment that makes you look smarter` Honestly, ***I*** find that offensive. There was no intention and no trace of bullying in my first comment. On the contrary, I believe that pointing out a fault with the question is doing the OP a favor in directing them to seek to improve it so that it can be understood and meaningfully answered. That's *not* putting them down at all. With that, I think we can agree to disagree, and I'll stop here.

Comment: @user450072 `I multiply the length of AC times the ∠A for example` Do you mean $\,AC \cdot \color{red}{\sin{\angle C}}\,$ instead? That will give you the length of the altitude from $\,A\,$, indeed, directly by the definition of the [sine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine). It's still not clear where the next highlighted paragraph fits into the question, though.

Comment: I'm using Cosine and it gives you where the altitude is.

Comment: @user450072 $AC \cdot \cos \angle A$ is the length of the projection of side $AC$ onto side $AB$. It is also the distance from $A$ to the foot of the altitude from $C$. The length of the altitude from $C$ *could* be then derived using Pythagoras' theorem as $\sqrt{AC^2 - (AC \cdot \cos \angle A)^2}= AC \cdot \sin \angle A$ if that's what you are asking, but that would be a very roundabout way to do it. (And it's still not clear what the second part of the question is supposed to mean.)

Comment: $\cos C=1-(\cos^2 A+\cos^2 B)$ ,and to find$\sin$ I use Pythagorean identity which makes it very easier.

Comment: @user450072 `cos C = 1 - (cos^2 A + cos^2 B)` That equality doesn't hold in general, neither as written, nor if you replace the LHS with `cos^2 C`. Sorry, I can't tell what it is that you are asking or claiming. I can only suggest that you edit any further clarifications into the question, rather than as comments.

Comment: I found the answer I'm looking and for that I thank you.I

Answer (score 0):

You can find the length of an altitude by multiplying length of a side by sine of an angle. For example, to find altitude AD to side BC, you multiple AB by sine of angle B or AC by sine of angle C.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be sides-lengths of the triangle $ABC$, $h_a$, $h_b$ and $h_c$ be altitudes of our triangle.

Thus,
$$h_a=\frac{2S_{\Delta ABC}}{a}=\frac{\sqrt{2(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2)-a^4-b^4-c^4}}{2a}$$

Comment: Just curious, what part of OP's question is this an answer to?

Comment: @dxiv See the title. I showed how we can find an altitude immediately, which was wanted. I wrote something wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong. But the *body* of the question asks more specifically `Can anyone elaborate if this is true or not?`, and that's the part I have trouble parsing.

Comment: @dxiv I think the question is "How to find altitudes in all triangles?" See the title.

Comment: Thank's for the answer .

Comment: @user450072 You are welcome!